# is there a way to embed flv files in java forms?

Tags: java, flash, swing, flv

I want to play some flash videos in my desktop application are there any tools (library,jar file, class... etc) to embed flvs in any java forms?

Comment: Embedding Flash into a Java application - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/221218/embedding-flash-flex-component-into-java-app