# Play Flash in Java (games)

Tags: java, flash

is there any way to play flash games in a java application? I saw jflashplayer, but it is commercial.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Embedding Flash / Flex component into Java app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/221218/embedding-flash-flex-component-into-java-app)

Answer (score 0):

Phew, not sure about this.

Can't you embed a browser window in which the flash plugin can run? Then you can load the app onto an HTML page which you instruct to load in the embedded browser window.