# Load Flash object in Java Web Browser

Tags: c#, java, flash, browser

I was wondering if there was some way to be able to load Flash objects from a custom Java web-browser. I want to be able to view YouTube videos for example.

I have read this: [Embedding Flash Component into Java App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/221218/embedding-flash-flex-component-into-java-app), but I am not sure how I would use this seeing as I do not have the Flash locally as a .swf. I do not know where it loads the Flash file from. Also, I would prefer the solution to not require buying a product.

I know for sure that this is do-able using C# and the WebBrowser class because that uses the Flash plugin for IE, I was just wondering if there was a way to do this with Java.